# Open set and Open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Can we replace "open interval" as "open set" in the definition of "NEIGHBORHOOD OF A POINT"?

Comment: Yes you can... But an open set may not be interval...

Comment: In topology a neighborhood of a point $x$ is commonly defined to be a set $N$ such that $x\in U\subseteq N$ for some open set $U$. It also happens that neighborhoods are requested to be open (Munkres).

Comment: Yes, you can. If you have an open interval then it is also an open set, and every open set contains open intervals around every point.

Comment: @dmtri examples??

Comment: The union of intervals (0,1) and (5,6) is open set but it is not interval

Comment: @Mark sir what about (1,2)U{3,4}.Is this an open interval?please sight reasons

Comment: No, an open interval is by definition a set of the form $(a,b)$ when $a<b$. $a$ and $b$ might also be infinite.

Comment: But still the above set can be seen as a neibourhood of 1/2 ...

Comment: @Mark thank u sir..is it an open set

Comment: @dmtri which set?

Comment: The one I wrote earlier.... ie (0,1) and (5,6) together

Comment: @dmtri why is it not an open interval??

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can even relax "open" and let neighborhood be defined as a set which contains an open set which contains the point. Most of the time on the real line, though, you only care about open, connected neighbourhoods. That is exactly what open intervals are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can because one can prove that,

> Every open set in $\mathbb R$ can be written as countable union of open intervals.

So once you have open set containing some point you can always find open subinterval containing same point.

So both definitions doesn’t give much difference except definition using open set is slightly general.

Comment: You can do that, only in case when you are working in the set of real numbers with the standard topology.